# RegEx PHP: Zero or more specific word without Word Boundaries

Tags: php, regex, string

Scenario:

```
$string = "CUSTOMER NAME JOE SOAPADDRESS 421 E DRACHMAN"
```

but sometimes it can be so

```
$string = "CUSTOMER NAME JOE SOAP"
```

**Target:**

An RegExp pattern to get only **JOE SOAP** where **ADDRESS** word *(and all that follows it)* may be present, as there can be no.

Something like:

```
$pattern = "/^CUSTOMER NAME (.+)[ADDRESS]*/"
```

but in this case, obviously, `[ADDRESS]*` means A or D or R or E or S zero or more.

Comment: Just `explode` with `"ADDRESS"`. See https://ideone.com/XqFWu0

Comment: You'd want to use grouping, not a character class here`[ADDRESS]*`. So `(ADDRESS)?`, the question marks makes the group optional. Would `ADDRESSADDRESS` be valid?

Comment: Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements list and expect others to do your job for you.

Comment: You're right, and I upvote you but I need to make an example, to have a direct and quick response to my question. It is useless to turn around to know what syntax should I use. If I had known, I would not have incommoded your availability. Therefore, please take note of my nickname, for the next times, and when you read it, please don't click on my question. My best excuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based matching:

```
^CUSTOMER NAME.+?(?=ADDRESS|$)
```

- This will match `CUSTOMER NAME JOE SOAP` in both cases.
- `(?=ADDRESS|$)` is positive lookahead to assert we have `ADDRESS` or end of line ahead thus giving us match upto position before that.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF0nR5/1)

Comment: Yeah. Great. It is the right one!!! I just add a group on JOE SOAP (for personal pourpose). Add: https://regex101.com/r/bF0nR5/2. Many thanks